# asp.net display joined tables in html with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, join

I finished this [asp.net tutorial](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html).

In the end i have 2 models with 2 scaffolded items.

Model Author

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ContosoBooks.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model Book

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ContosoBooks.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 500)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }

        // Navigation property
        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now i want to join this two table by AuthorID and simply display my one, merged table in main view.

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the LINQ to join these two model classes to get the merged Result into a custom View Model object list called mergedResultViewModel. The TestDBContext in the following code is EF's dbContext.

```
var query = from au in TestDBContext.Authors join bk in TestDBContext.Books on au.AuthorID equals bk.AuthorID
    select new MergedResultViewModel { au.AuthorID, au.FirstMidName, bk.BookID, bk.Title, bk.Year, bk.Price, bk.Genre }

var mergedResultViewModel = query.ToList();
```

The type MergedResultViewModel can be defined as following in the code file.

```
public class MergedResultViewModel
    {
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: OK, but then how i can display mergedResult in my html view ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Assuming that you are using MVC, once you have the mergedResultViewModel (which is a list of your custom object MergedResultViewModel), it can be used to create an MVC list view using scaffolding.

Comment: Can you post for me all mergedResultViewModel .cs file ?

Comment: Added the code to define the class for the ViewModel